# How to get CloudWatch Event name in Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a CloudWatch scheduled event invoking a Lambda function.

The event is currently passing a JSON with some parameters. One of which contains the event name, handwritten, which isn't very elegant and can lead to typos.

[image]

I cannot choose to pass the `Matched event`, as I am also passing some other parameters as JSON.

[image]

So I would somehow need to pass the event as a parameter in that JSON object, but I couldn't find any docs about that.

How can I get the invoking event name inside the Lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use input transformer which can be used to add your own stuff plus something from the meta data available. In your case

Input path will be

`{"ruleName":"$.resources[0]"}`

While the Input template will be

`{"yourKey": "yourValue", "ruleName": <ruleName>}`

The screenshot is here [image: screenshot]

And this is how it will be available in your lambda function

```
{
  yourKey: 'yourValue',
  ruleName: 'arn:aws:events:someregion:someaccountId:rule/testevent'
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works! Reference to the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-Input-Transformer-Tutorial.html